# how can i position a button inside a grid div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grid, position

```
<div className={classes.productSection}>
      {available.map((product)=>
        (<div key={product.id} className={product.availability? classes.productBox : classes.notavailBox}>
          <h4>{product.user.companyName}</h4>
          <p>{product.user.district}</p>
          {product.availability && <button className={classes.cartButton}>Add</button> }
        </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
```

this is the styling

```
.productSection {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  animation: append-animate .5s linear;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  
}
.productBox {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1.5px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

the problem is I couldn't position the button. when using absolute positioning, it is positioned depend on the body not the parent element.
I need a button in the right side of the parent div and vertically centered.

Answer (score 1):

For the button be to positioned absolute depending on the parent you need to add this property to the parent:

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 1):

A cool feature about CSS Grid is that you can use you can use properties like:

- justify-self: start;  (usually horizontal left)
- justify-self: center; (usually horizontal center)
- justify-self: end;    (usually horizontal right)
  and
- align-self: start;    (usually vertical top)
- align-self: center;   (usually vertical center)
- align-self: end;      (usually vertical bottom)

You apply the properties on the child element of a parent element that has display: grid. to move the selected child, Try them out. hope this helps.

Comment: Also using this approach means you don't have to add the position: x; property and it automatically takes care of responsiveness for you via the objects moving/sticking to the location you set them.